# MS-DOS show a list of excecuted commands

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos, tail

I'm trying to see a list of commands which are executed in windows once I run a specific function within an application.

So for example, if I was to use Ms Word to save a file, I would like to see a list of commands which are used to accomplish this tasks.

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both cmd.exe and ms-dos? cmd.exe is used by the NT series, in which ms-dos isn't used unless you run a DOS application, and even on windows 9x the use of DOS was little more than a compatibility wrapper around DOS drivers.

Comment: Windows applications use the Windows API to interact with the OS, just like console applications use the API. Most operations will not have a corresponding command line tool. If you want to monitor API calls, there are various [API monitor](https://www.google.com/search?q=API+monitor+windows), but I haven't used any of them recently, so I can't recommend a particular one.

Comment: DOS won't allow you to see calls done to the system as most of the calls are 32/64-bit and use API as said above. Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to check all the actions done by the software (access to the registry, file system, etc.)